# Can't understand instructions in Javascript

Tags: javascript

So, I have a task assigned to me but I find that the instructions is a little deep and english isn't my native language. So here's the instructions:

- Write an expression that operates on a variable called `move`
- if a `move` has a value, your expression should evaluate to that value.
- However, if 'move' is not specified / is null, your expression should equal `getInput()`.

And here's how I've seen it:

```
var move = getInput();
if (move === getInput) {
    console.log("Player: " + move);
}
else if (move === null) {
    getInput():
};
return getInput (move);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `Truthy` and `Falsy` values

`getInput` is a function. When you get to

```
if (move === getInput) // rest of code
```

This is checking to see if the result of calling getInput() is the reference to the function itself ... this is probably not what you want.

#### If checks for `Truthy` values.

`null` is not truthy so a sufficient test for your input would be

```
if (move) // rest of code.
```

move will be populated with getting the input. so thats why it will make sense to console.log it in the body of the if statement.

---

#### Further more

you don't need to explicity check using `else if` because you are checking a direct negation of your if.

so instead your format should be

```
if (move) {
// ...
} else { // no need for else if here. null is implied.
// ...
}
```